# different result from recursive and dynamic programming

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Working on below problem,

**Problem**,

Given a m * n grids, and one is allowed to move up or right, find the different paths between two grid points.

I write a recursive version and a dynamic programming version, but they return different results, and any thoughts what is wrong?

**Source code**,

```
from collections import defaultdict
def move_up_right(remaining_right, remaining_up, prefix, result):
    if remaining_up == 0 and remaining_right == 0:
        result.append(''.join(prefix[:]))
        return
    if remaining_right > 0:
        prefix.append('r')
        move_up_right(remaining_right-1, remaining_up, prefix, result)
        prefix.pop(-1)
    if remaining_up > 0:
        prefix.append('u')
        move_up_right(remaining_right, remaining_up-1, prefix, result)
        prefix.pop(-1)
def move_up_right_v2(remaining_right, remaining_up):
    # key is a tuple (given remaining_right, given remaining_up),
    # value is solutions in terms of list
    dp = defaultdict(list)
    dp[(0,1)].append('u')
    dp[(1,0)].append('r')
    for right in range(1, remaining_right+1):
        for up in range(1, remaining_up+1):
            for s in dp[(right-1,up)]:
                dp[(right,up)].append(s+'r')
            for s in dp[(right,up-1)]:
                dp[(right,up)].append(s+'u')
    return dp[(right, up)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = []
    move_up_right(2,3,[],result)
    print result
    print '============'
    print move_up_right_v2(2,3)
```

Comment: It might help to include your input data, output data and expected output data in the question.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, my input data is included in source code, see `2,3,[],result`, which is move 2 steps to right and 3 steps to up. If you have any ideas to my original question, it will be great.

Comment: What more do you hope for than [bunji's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41668380/3789665)?

Comment: @greybeard, it is already good, thanks all the same.

Comment: @greybeard, I have some new thoughts on the problem and have a new post, if you have any thoughts, it will be great => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689176/grid-move-algorithm-implementation-in-dynamic-programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 2 you should be starting your for loops at 0 not at 1.  By starting at 1 you are missing possible permutations where you traverse the bottom row or leftmost column first.

Change version 2 to:

```
def move_up_right_v2(remaining_right, remaining_up):
    # key is a tuple (given remaining_right, given remaining_up),
    # value is solutions in terms of list
    dp = defaultdict(list)
    dp[(0,1)].append('u')
    dp[(1,0)].append('r')
    for right in range(0, remaining_right+1):
        for up in range(0, remaining_up+1):
            for s in dp[(right-1,up)]:
                dp[(right,up)].append(s+'r')
            for s in dp[(right,up-1)]:
                dp[(right,up)].append(s+'u')
    return dp[(right, up)]
```

And then:

```
result = []
move_up_right(2,3,[],result)

set(move_up_right_v2(2,3)) == set(result)
True
```

And just for fun... another way to do it:

```
from itertools import permutations

list(map(''.join, set(permutations('r'*2+'u'*3, 5))))
```

Comment: Thanks bunji for the reply, vote up and mark it as answer. Grant bounty points.

Comment: BTW, bunji, I have some new thoughts on the problem and have a new post, if you have any thoughts, it will be great => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689176/grid-move-algorithm-implementation-in-dynamic-programming

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the dynamic programming version is that it doesn't take into account the paths that start from more than one move up (`'uu...'`) or more than one move right (`'rr...'`).

Before executing the main loop you need to fill `dp[(x,0)]` for every `x` from `1` to `remaining_right+1` and `dp[(0,y)]` for every `y` from `1` to `remaining_up+1`.

In other words, replace this:

```
dp[(0,1)].append('u')
dp[(1,0)].append('r')
```

with this:

```
for right in range(1, remaining_right+1):
    dp[(right,0)].append('r'*right)
for up in range(1, remaining_up+1):
    dp[(0,up)].append('u'*up)
```

Comment: BTW, user3290797, I have some new thoughts on the problem and have a new post, if you have any thoughts, it will be great => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689176/grid-move-algorithm-implementation-in-dynamic-programming